# How to check iOS app size before upload

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, 3g

I would like to be able to check the size of my app before submitting to the app store. More specifically I need to know whether it will be below the magic 20 MB, to allow cellular downloads, since the app is created for a festival.

Comment: Just a FYI to anyone reading, as of May 31st, 2019 the cell download limit is 200mb. See https://9to5mac.com/2019/05/31/apple-iphone-cellular-limit-increased/

Comment: Actually, looks like this limit can now be overridden by the user. https://9to5mac.com/2019/06/03/ios-13-removes-200-mb-file-size-limit-for-app-downloads-over-cellular/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The install file downloaded from the App Store will vary based on the device and what thinning is done to your app. An ad hoc distribution .ipa file will give an estimate of how big the install file from the App Store will be. Archive your app in Xcode, then make an ad hoc distribution. If you turn off app thinning while making this file you'll see the biggest your install file could be. If you turn on app thinning and generate all the variations of .ipa files you'll see all the different install file sizes.

To see an even more accurate answer to this question, submit your app to TestFlight. In the TestFlight app on your devices you can see the size of the app by checking the app details. Check it on multiple devices, it will vary if the app thinning process considers your devices sufficiently different and uses different assets from your app archive.

Below is my original answer:

In Xcode 4: Once your app is ready for distribution, archive the app. In the Organizer, select the Archives tab. Select your app in the left hand column. Select the latest archive in the right hand column. Hit the Share... button in the top section. Save the file as an .ipa. Check file size in the Finder.

Comment: Just FYI: an IPA file is just a zip file :) The final step before uploading to the app store is for you to to zip your app - you can just check the size of that zipped file :) (saves you having to build an archive)

Comment: In xCode 4 the built-in app loader takes care of all that, so the "Share..."-button approach was the way to go!

Comment: The .ipa size does not represent the final app binary size, please check my answer to this question.

Answer (score 46):

This question is quite old, but IMO still relevant. Here is a recent message I received from Apple when I uploaded an app for review:

> The app binary listed below was 79.7 MB when you submitted it, but will be 132.2 MB once processed for the App Store. This exceeds the cellular network download size limit and would require your app to be downloaded over Wi-Fi.

**There is no way to know this '*once processed for the App Store*' size until you've submitted your app.**

There is a feature within the Organizer/Archives view that allows you to estimate your final app size. I have found this estimate is inaccurate. Here is the button you're looking for if you want to see this estimate:

[image]

So what I have learned is that the "processed for the App Store" part above will mean your .ipa file is not an accurate measure of the final app size users will download. The Organizer/Archives estimation is incorrect, it seems the estimation is higher than the actual size, for example an archive sent for review was estimated at ~109 MB, the final app size in the store was ~90 MB and the .ipa filesize was ~47 MB.

**Why is the final size larger than the .ipa?**

I'd also like to know the answer to this, from what I understand it's related to DRM things that Apple adds to the .ipa.

**UPDATE (June 2015)**

The latest version of Xcode does not have the 'Estimated App Store Size' option within the 'Organizer' view.

**UPDATE (November 2017)**

Estimated size information is available on App Store Connect:

> My Apps > App > Activity > Select a build > App Store File Sizes

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In the current version of XCode (4.5 as of writing) you just have to click Product > Archive. The Archives tab of the Organiser will open and the estimated size in the app store is just displayed in one of the information fields when the archive is selected.

Answer (score 7):

For now, using Xcode > 10 you could get a real size of your *.ipa`files going through Xcode archivation workflow. When you'll take an archive, open user's folder w/ archived projects. Location is`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`. Here you will find your last archived project, with`.xcarchive` extension. Click on it, and Xcode opens a window with all your projects which have been archived ever before.

Then, select yours and click on the right menu the `Distribute App` button. Select `Ad hoc`, which needs to export your builded .ipa locally. And when you will build it, store in any folder. Your folder should be named like `Stage 2019-06-27 10-14-30`. And inside this folder you'll find a file named like `App Thinning Size Report`. This file contains all info about any .ipa file for different devices with differenet iOS versions and it's compressed/uncompressed size.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **Build & Archive** your application, and then you can check the size of you `IPA` file.

*IPA archive (**IP**hone **A**pp) is the file which is downloaded by users from the App Store*

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 8, since the estimate size button disappeared, one way to get a very close estimation (in my case the AppStore version is exactly + 2mb) is :

- Archive your application
- Export your application for "iOS App Store Deployment"
- Extract the generated IPA (fast way, rename it to zip and double click)
- Go to the .app (Payload/YOUR_APPLICATION)
- Compress it (zip it with default finder action)

Et voilà :-)

Comment: How this takes into consideration architecture slicing?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through App Store Connect:

1. Choose your app within App Store Connect
2. Select "Activity"
3. Select "All Build" on the left pane
4. Choose the build and look for "Compressed File Size"

Answer (score 1):

If you have tested your app on your device during development for the final time before you are ready to upload to App Store, you can go to "Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage" and scroll down the list of apps and find yours. Each app has size listed. That should be a good estimate of your app size.

Answer (score 0):

Build the application, get the .app file in your products folder, Reveal in finder and select the app and right click, choose "Get Info" to see the size of the application.

Comment: Hmm.. The only .app file I can find in my products folder is far smaller than the expected outcome..

Comment: How accurate is that compared to Apple's final calculation?