# iOS app size analysis before and after integrating a 3rd party framework

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to analyze iOS app size comparison before and after integrating a 3rd party framework to see how much the app size increases due to that 3rd party framework.

Following are the steps I'm following,

Before Integrating 3rd party framework:
1. Created a new Xcode project called "SampleTestApp". 
2. Cleaned
3. Edit the scheme to set "Release" build configuration
4. Build  the project for device
Check the App size under "Products". It shows "24.6 MB on disk"

After Integrating 3rd party framework:
1. Drag and drop the 3rd party framework into Xcode project "SampleTestApp"
2. Cleaned
3. Build  the project for device
4. Check the App size under "Products". There is no change in the App size. It is showing the App size same as "24.6 MB on disk"

5. I have included `import framework` in a class file.
6. Build  the project again for device
7. It is showing the App size now as "25.6 MB on disk"

Can I conclude this 3rd framework increases only "1 MB" in my existing App? This framework is going to launch device camera, and allow users to take photo and analyze. That's all it will do.

Please note, it is not the Appstore app to check through iTunes Connect etc. It's from the Xcode project from my system locally. I am using Xcode 8.2.1.

Please suggest if any other checks I can do apart from this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check iOS app size before upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411397/how-to-check-ios-app-size-before-upload)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411397/how-to-check-ios-app-size-before-upload

Comment: @Stella I can answer this question but I think those links ^ can help you understand that is difficult to estimate the final size of an app including a 3rd party framework.  Different platforms, App Thinning, Bitcode, etc. can change the size of it. You can estimate the size by using http://stackoverflow.com/a/26585279/3641812 or by the iTunes Connect (App > Activity > Select a build > Build Details > App Store File Sizes).

Comment: Please note, it is not the Appstore app to check through iTunes Connect etc. It's from the Xcode project from my system locally. I am using Xcode 8.2.1.